# How to combine equality operators in an if statement in java?

Tags: java, operators

In python, you can do

```
if(a!=b!=c)
```

How can you do the same thing in Java without having to separate them and write all the "&&" operators? I'm trying to check that all 10 elements are not equal, and I don't want to have to write the equality statement 45 times.

Comment: You have 10 distinct variables? That sounds something that should be an array, and compared with a `for` statement.

Comment: You could write a method that takes a vararg or a container and compare them all and return a single boolean value.

Comment: I don't think the Python code does quite what you want. "Note that a opa b opb c doesn't imply any kind of comparison between a and c" (http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/comparisons.html)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that operation in Java. Note furthermore that if `a`, `b`, etc., are not primitives, then you should probably be using `equals` instead of `==` (or `!=`). The latter only check for object identity, not equality of values.

If you want to check whether 10 elements are all distinct, you can throw them into a `Set` implementation (such as `HashSet`) and check that the set contains 10 elements. Or better (thanks to @allonhadaya for the comment), check that each element was added. Here's a generic method that works for an arbitrary number of objects of arbitrary type:

```
public static <T> boolean areDistinct(T... elements) {
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T element : elements) {
        if (!set.add(element)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If your elements are primitives (e.g., `int`), then you can write a non-generic version for the specific type.

Comment: @Ted Hopp you can implement a sort of short-circuiting by checking the return value of mySet.Add. If it returns false, there is a duplicate; Otherwise, continue to the next element. After iterating through all elements, they are all distinct. This may be a micro-optimization for this case, but it is worth keeping in mind. Take a look at this example: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-check-or-detect-duplicate.html

Comment: @allonhadaya - Nice. I added this idea to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something wrong in your program, if you need to compare 45 variables.
Try to use arrays and cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `Set` is probably the most efficient solution, but if you need to supply some kind of customization to the comparison, you could use something like...

```
Comparable[] values = new Comparable[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
boolean matches = true;
for (int outter = 0; outter < values.length; outter++) {
    for (int inner = outter + 1; inner < values.length; inner++) {
        matches &= values[outter].compareTo(values[inner]) == 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

Comment: OP said they didn't want to do that.

Comment: @Makoto And I don't want to eat my vegetables ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer `Set` will use the `equals` and `hashCode` methods which can be overridden for a customized comparison.

Comment: @allonhadaya that's a lot of work if all you want to do is make a quick comparison on some arbitrary field. You don't always want to change the behaviour of hashcode or equals globally

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option in java (you cannot do such thing without using &&). Java is not Python

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, no, there's no native way to do this in Java.

But, why don't we implement the syntactic sugar for Python's `all` method instead?  With varargs, it's not difficult.  It does have an O(n) runtime cost, though.

```
public static boolean all(Boolean... theBools) {
    Boolean result = Boolean.TRUE;
    for(Boolean b : theBools) {
        if(null == b || !b) {
            result = Boolean.FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can use it then like this:

```
if(YourClass.all(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)) {
    // something to do if ALL of them are true
}
```

Comment: How is testing this related to OP's problem?

Comment: @Makoto I believe the OP wants to check for distinction between values rather than the logical `AND` of a variadic boolean argument list.

Comment: @allonhadaya:  I disagree.  In Python, that construct is [syntactically equivalent](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) to `all((a, b, c))`, which [does a similar operation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for pointing that out, but I'm not sure I follow. The `a, b, and c` in the question don't seem to be boolean values.

Comment: Well, generically speaking, they might not be.  They could be integers or strings or even characters.  If that is honestly the case, then the `Set` approach which Ted Hopp went for would be ideal.

Comment: @Makoto Aha, yet another case of ambiguous question. Thanks for clarifying.